# How do I create a list / table which is divided into sections?

Tags: tables, lists

I would like to add a list / table in Latex which is devided into sections, but I can't figure out how it goes.
It should look something like this:
[image]

Here is a table that I think could lead into the right direction.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
% why not '\usepackage[spanish]{babel}'?

% New:
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,array,threeparttable}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\textbf{before}}
\begin{table}[!h]
            \small
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7} 
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |} 
                    \hline
                    \textbf{nº} & \textbf{CID Ligando} & \textbf{Nombre Ligando} & \textbf{Afinidad (Kcal/mol)²} & \textbf{RMSD l.b.} & \textbf{RMSD u.b.}  \\ \hline
                    1 & 234523 & LoreIpsum & 234 & 0 & 0 \\
                    2 & 2345 & LoreIpsum & 2365 & 0 & 0 \\
                    3 & 3453 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    4 & 83452 & LoreIpsum & 2456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    5 & 210 & LoreIpsum & 245 & 0 & 0 \\
                    6 & 3417 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    7 & 4345 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    8 & 4334 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \newline\newline
                \caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
                \label{tab:version1}
            \end{center}
\end{table}

%% after
\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\textbf{after}}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=6.0] l S[table-format=5.0] cc @{}} 
\toprule
{nº} & {CID Ligando} & {Nombre Ligando} & {Afinidad} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{RMSD} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){5-6}
& & & {(Kcal/mol)\textsuperscript{2}} & {l.b.} & {u.b.}\\
\midrule
  1 & 234523 & LoremIpsum & 234   & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 2345   & LoremIpsum & 2365  & 0 & 0 \\ 
  3 & 3453   & LoremIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
  4 & 83452  & LoremIpsum & 2456  & 0 & 0 \\
\addlinespace
  5 & 210    & LoremIpsum & 245   & 0 & 0 \\
  6 & 3417   & LoremIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
  7 & 4345   & LoremIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
  8 & 4334   & LoremIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
\label{tab:version2}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to begin with. Maybe you can have a look at [tablesgenerator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As skeleton. In it you can insert/fulfill real text and extend to more row groups. For table I use `tabularray` package, however, you can use also `tabularx` or other tables in which you need to set column specifications accordingly and use their syntax for multi row cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l X[0.5, l] X[l] l l @{}},
             row{1} = {m}
             }
    \toprule
Set & Attribute & Description   & Variable  & {Data\\ Type} \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=5]{l} Recency
    & text text & \lipsum[1][1]     & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][2]     & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][3]     & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][4-5]   & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][6]     & sens\_rec & float     \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{l} Frequency
    & text text & texz text         & sens\_rec & int       \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][1-2]   & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][3-4]   & sens\_rec & int       \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][5-6]   & sens\_rec & float     \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][7-8]   & sens\_rec & int       \\
    & text text & \lipsum[1][9]     & sens\_rec & float     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: You may found helpful to read some introductory text about tables. For example [wiki: tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).